# Jelastic Apache SSH connection

Tags: apache, ssh, jelastic

How can I connect via SSH to a Apache server in Jelastic ?

I've searched high and low, but couldn't find the right answer.

thanks

Comment: Web server and hosting related question, should not use php tag.

Comment: there is no php tag, but there was PHP mentioned in the title - this is however corrected.

Comment: Unless you're trying to connect via SSH from a Jelastic instance you'd probably want to post in superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jelastic is currently not providing SSH - This will be added in the upcoming release in a couple of months.
The reason I need to have SSH, is so that I can do composer installs.

Thanks for all replys and comments.

UPDATE -

It is now possible to use SSH on a Jelastic Envrionment

Answer (score 0):

Jelastic is a managed PaaS - so there is no SSH access. You can access all config files right in the Jelastic dashboard: why do you want SSH?

Comment: Hi, I am 'taking a ride' in this discussion. Damien, in my specific case, I would like to install Drush, the Drupal CMS command line tool. In order to fire Drush commands, I have to navigate to the folder where my web based Drupal CMS application is located. This is probably a use case where SSH access would be useful in Jelastic. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcosBuarque - watch this space :)